# Changing an array entry within a json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

I've pulled json from a File using NodeJS's fs.createReadStream() and I'm now finding difficulty writing data back into the File (already parsing and then stringifying as appropriate).

The Discord-Bot I'm developing deletes text-channels then 'recreates' them (with the same title) to clear chat - it grabs the channel IDs dynamically and puts them in a file, until the channels are deleted.
However, the file-writing procedure ends up in errors.

This was my first attempt:

```
let channels_json = fs.createReadStream()
//let channels_json = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}\\..\\json\\channels.json`);                        
let obj = (JSON.parse(channels_json)).channelsToClear;
let i = 0;
obj.forEach(id => {
    i++;
    if(id === originalId){
        obj[i] = channela.id;                                
    }
});
obj += (JSON.parse(channels_json)).infoChannel;
obj += "abc";
json = JSON.stringify(obj);
channels_json.write(json);
```

This was my second:

```
let id_to_replace = message.guild.channels.get(channels[channel]).id;
//let channels_json = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}\\..\\json\\channels.json`);
let obj;
let channels_json = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}\\..\\json\\channels.json`,function(err,data){
    if (err) throw err;
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if (obj["channelsToClear"].indexOf(id_to_replace) > -1) {
        obj["channelsToClear"][obj["channelsToClear"].indexOf(id_to_replace)] = channela.id;
        //then replace the json file with new parsed one
        channels_json.writeFile(`${__dirname}\\..\\json\\channels.json`, JSON.stringify(obj), function(){
            console.log("Successfully replaced channels.json contents");
        });
        //channels_json.end();
    }
});
```

The final outcome was to update the 'channelsToClear' array within the json file with new channel-IDs. Console/Node output varied, all of which had to do with "create channels with an options object" or "Buffer.write" (all irrelevant) - the json file remained unchanged..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Streams incorrectly. You can't write back out through a read stream.

For a simple script type thing, streaming is probably overkill. Streams are quite a bit more complicated and while worth it for high-efficienty applications but not for something that looks like it is going to be relatively quick.

Use the `fs.readFileSync` and `fs.writeFileSync` to get and write the data instead.

As far as your actual searching for and replacing the channel, I think either approach would work, but assuming there is only ever going to be one replacement, the second approach is probably better.